# How to make stacked line chart with different y-axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am wondering how should I make stacked line chart which is gonna take different columns in matplotlib. The point is when we are doing aggregation, I need to do data aggregation on two different columns, I think I need to make one big dataframe that will be used for plotting. I didn't find prettier and handy way to do this in pandas, matplotlib. Can anyone suggest possible tweaks to do this? any ideas?

**my attempt**

this is the first aggregation I need to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/4657714653398e9269263a7c8ad4bb8a/raw/fa6709a0c41888503509e569ace63606d2e5c2ff/mydf.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['date'])

df_re = df[df['retail_item'].str.contains("GROUND BEEF")]
df_rei = df_re.groupby(['date', 'retail_item']).agg({'number_of_ads': 'sum'})
df_rei = df_rei.reset_index(level=[0,1])
df_rei['week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_rei['date']).week
df_rei['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_rei['date']).year
df_rei['week'] = df_rei['date'].dt.strftime('%W').astype('uint8')

df_ret_df1 = df_rei.groupby(['retail_item', 'week'])['number_of_ads'].agg([max, min, 'mean']).stack().reset_index(level=[2]).rename(columns={'level_2': 'mm', 0: 'vals'}).reset_index()
```

and this is second aggregation that I need to do which is similar to first one except I am choosing different column now:

```
df_re['price_gap'] = df_re['high_price'] - df_re['low_price']
dff_rei1 = df_re.groupby(['date', 'retail_item']).agg({'price_gap': 'mean'})
dff_rei1 = dff_rei1.reset_index(level=[0,1])
dff_rei1['week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dff_rei1['date']).week
dff_rei1['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dff_rei1['date']).year
dff_rei1['week'] = dff_rei1['date'].dt.strftime('%W').astype('uint8')

dff_ret_df2 = dff_rei1.groupby(['retail_item', 'week'])['price_gap'].agg([max, min, 'mean']).stack().reset_index(level=[2]).rename(columns={'level_2': 'mm', 0: 'vals'}).reset_index()
```

now I am struggling how can I combine the output of first, second aggregation into one dataframe for making stacked line chart. Is that possible to do so?

**goal**:

I want to make stacked line charts where its y axis is taking different columns such as y axis should show # of ads, and price range, while x-axis shows 52 week period. This is partial code I attempted to make line chart:

```
for g, d in df_ret_df1.groupby('retail_item'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4), dpi=144)
    sns.lineplot(x='week', y='vals', hue='mm', data=d,alpha=.8)
    y1 = d[d.mm == 'max']
    y2 = d[d.mm == 'min']
    plt.fill_between(x=y1.week, y1=y1.vals, y2=y2.vals)
    
    for year in df['year'].unique():
        data = df_rei[(df_rei.date.dt.year == year) & (df_rei.retail_item == g)]
        sns.lineplot(x='week', y='price_gap', ci=None, data=data,label=year,alpha=.8)
```

is there any elegant way so we can construct plotting data where data aggregation on different columns can be done easily in pandas? Is there other way around to make this happen? any thoughts?

**desired output**:

here is the desired output that I want to get:
[image]

How should I make plotting data in order to get my desired plot like this? Any idea?

Comment: One reason for the lack of answers may be that we have to retro-engineer what you try to achieve with your two aggregations. I suggest adding a description of what these steps do and what the final graph is supposed to show. I also have error messages such as `NameError: name 'cmap' is not defined`.

Comment: @Mr.T I attached my final desired plot and fixed the error. I made bounty of this question, do you have any better ideas on this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to look into the problem. Maybe later this week but I assume somebody else will by then have solved your problem.

Comment: To me, this question looks like a duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67393421/14148248). It would have been better to clarify your previous question rather than post a new one. I will see about editing [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67462270/14148248) to provide a solution according to the desired output that you have now provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas groupby feature is very versatile, and you can reduce the lines of code considerably to achieve the final dataframe for plotting.

```
plotdf = df_re.groupby([ 'retail_item',df_re['date'].dt.year,df_re['date'].dt.week]).agg({'number_of_ads':'sum','price_gap':'mean'}).unstack().T
```

Once you have the aggregation done the right way, use a for loop to show each of the measures needed in a different plot. Plot a shaded range by using pandas describe feature to compute the min and max on the fly:

```
f,axs = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(20,14))
axs=axs.ravel()

for i,x in enumerate(['number_of_ads','price_gap']):
    plotdf.loc[x].plot(rot=90,grid=True,ax=axs[i])
    plotdf.loc[x].T.describe().T[['min','max']].plot(kind='area',color=['w','grey'],alpha=0.3,ax=axs[i],title= x)
```

[image]

Edit with updated code:

```
plotdf = df_re.groupby(['retail_item',df_re['date'].dt.year,df_re['date'].dt.week]).agg({'number_of_ads':'sum','weighted_avg':'mean'}).unstack().T
f,axs = plt.subplots(3,2,figsize=(20,14))
axs=axs.ravel()
i=0
for col in plotdf.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    for x in ['number_of_ads','weighted_avg']:
        plotdf.loc[x,col].plot(rot=90,grid=True,ax=axs[i]);
      plotdf.loc[x,col].T.describe().T[['min','max']].plot(kind='area',color=['w','grey'],alpha=0.3,ax=axs[i],title= col+', '+x)
        i+=1
```

Comment: why there is not data shows up between week 17 to week 45? I know the structure of plot is looks right, but the plot itself is not right. Any possible updates you can make? instead of using price_range, we can use weighted_avg on y-axis, in that case how that possible output going to be? any updates? Thanks!

Comment: The source data has been changed - it does not contain 2019 data any more. If you update it, it will show up. As for weighted_avg, yes, it is possible to get any measure you want, you'll just need to write an aggregation function instead of the 'mean' in the first line: 'price_gap':'mean'

Comment: when I do aggregation on weighted_avg, it got error. Do you mind to add code lines if we want to aggregate on weighted_avg instead? Also, could we separate out subplots by years, such as each retail items for 2020, 2021 in one stacked plot? Can we do this using for loop to iterate by retail items where each stacked plot shows specific items for 2020, 2021 data of # of ads and price range? how can we do that just like what I showed in desired plot? any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: I was able to run it with weighted_avg instead of price_gap. Please check your code. The edited code above produces 6 charts,  2 for each product. Please mark as answer if all of your original questions are addressed.

Comment: can we aggregate high, low, and weight average prices on y axis while keep exactly same format you showed in updated attempt? Is that doable? Do you mind to show how should we approach that? I am going to accept the answer for sure but this questions is dangling around me. Thanks again for your help!